# Spring boot application failed to start with exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using spring boot v2.5.2. Below is my folder structure and code. This is simple test project.

My folder structure:

[image]

**RESTController Class:**

```
package com.user.UserManagementSystem.controller;

import com.user.UserManagementSystem.model.User;
import com.user.UserManagementSystem.service.UserServiceImpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")

public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.getUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.user.UserManagementSystem.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
    
@Entity
@Table(name= "Users")
public class User {

    public User() {
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name ="userName")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name ="language")
    private String language;
    
    @Column(name ="mobileNumber")
    private int mobileNumber;

    public User(String userName, String name, String language, int mobileNumber) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.name = name;
        this.language = language;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public int getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(int mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.user.UserManagementSystem.repository;

import com.user.UserManagementSystem.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.user.UserManagementSystem.service;

import com.user.UserManagementSystem.model.User;
import java.util.List;


public interface UserService {

    List<User> getUsers();

    User getUserById(Long id);

    User addUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(Long id);

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.user.UserManagementSystem.service;

import com.user.UserManagementSystem.repository.UserRepository;
import com.user.UserManagementSystem.model.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;    
    
 
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
}
```

**UserManangmentSystemApplication.java**

```
package com.user.UserManangmentSystem;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.user.UserManangmentSystem", "com.user.UserManagementSystem.controller", "com.user.UserManagementSystem.repository", "com.user.UserManagementSystem.service"})
//@SpringBootApplication
public class UserManangmentSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserManangmentSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/ums
spring.datasource.username=ums
spring.datasource.password=ums
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect

server.port=8888
debug=true
```

When it build the project i am getting :

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.user.UserManagementSystem.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correct package structure it will collect all bean within base package and sub package also. No need explicitly mention package scan. If you have any spell mistakes then that error will occur.

Comment: Wondering How this answer was helpful and mine was not?

Comment: I voted your may be forget scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

Typo in your base package name which makes packages different.

Change

```
com.user.UserManangmentSystem
```

To

```
com.user.UserManangementSystem
```

Correct management spelling.

Comment: @developer did my answer helped?